# What is the name of the fallacy characterized by "All A are B; therefore all B are A"?

Tags: logic, fallacies

What is the name of this fallacy? I can't seem to find any reference to it on the 'net. It may seem too simple to be a common fallacy, but I don't find that to be the case.

For instance, Hume (it can be argued) says that the only things that are right are things we prefer. A possible objection to this might be, "So then you're claiming that everything someone wants or prefers is right?" An answer to that, of course, is that just because everything that is right is something we prefer, that does not imply that everything we prefer is right.

I'm not interested in getting into a discussion on Hume; I'm just trying to lay out a case where this fallacy might come into play.

Comment: You might need to be careful in your interpretation here. "Only things that are right are things we prefer" and "Everything we prefer is right" are logically equivalent. "Only X is Y" is equivalent to "All Y is X".

Comment: Its intriguing how close that "logic" gets to induction.  That might be why it's so hard for people.

Comment: "Only things that are right are things we prefer" is not the same thing as "the only things that are right are things we prefer." The second one says 'everything that is right is something we prefer'; the first says 'everything we prefer is right.' That's just precisely the distinction I want to make here.

Comment: @KevinHolmes is right, but his comment is irrelevant and apparently also confusing here. It simply doesn't have anything to do with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example would be an example of an invalid **conversion** of a [categorical proposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_proposition) in *A-form* (All A are B). Such conversions are valid in *E* and *I* forms (*E-form*: No A are B; *I-form*: Some A are B), but not in *A-form*. I don't know about a particular term to label this fallacy, except **converse error** (or a [categorical converse fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_(logic)#Categorical_converse)), but all the terms [suggested](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/30753/2953) in Keelan's answer sounds suitable.

To me, a set formulation of this is most clear, where A ⊆ B ↛ B ⊆ A.

Answer (score 5):

This is called [**affirming the consequent**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent):

> **Affirming the consequent**, sometimes called **converse error**, **fallacy of the converse** or **confusion of necessity and sufficiency**, is a [formal fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_fallacy) of inferring the [converse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_(logic)) from the original statement. The corresponding argument has the general [form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_form):
>
> 1. If P, then Q.
> 2. Q.
> 3. Therefore, P.

Comment: This is kind of a pet peeve of mine, but should universal affirmative propositions really be glossed as material conditionals like that?

Comment: @KevinHolmes this is a quote. I can't help what is written there. Anyway, there's an obvious relationship between a predicate P(x) = x ∈ P and the set P = { x | P(x) }. Here, P and Q are simply instances of predicates P(x) and Q(x) for particular x, which shows that the fallacy described in the citation also applies in the case of the OP.

Comment: As KH implies, this does not really match the question. For instance, the "therefore" does not occur in the same logical place here as there.

Comment: @JeffY yes, it does. The set A in the question is equivalent with the membership predicate P(x) of which P is a particular instance, and similarly  with B and Q. I explained this already above. If you think something is incorrect, you should point out *how* it is incorrect instead of simply stating that it *is* incorrect - that isn't really constructive.

Comment: Just do the correspondence between notations: "All A are B" <==> if (x∈A), then (x∈B); "All B are A" <==> if (x∈B), then (x∈A). There is only one "if ... then" construct in this answer, therefore it does not correspond precisely to the question. (The added "gloss" to which KH refers is going (silently) from "2.Q;3.Therefore, P." to "Therefore if Q, then P.")

Comment: Here is a rather clear explication of the distinction: http://www.patheos.com/blogs/secularoutpost/2013/02/24/implication-vs-entailment/

Comment: @JeffY yes, the two are not literally the same, but the difference is irrelevant. You can perfectly rewrite my quote to make it fit. The fallacy is the same in both cases.